# Get value from td contenteditable in the table and push to array in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to get all values from `qty` column, and in the qty column I was put contenteditable="true" [here is pic of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPw9t.png)

`var ids_selected = []`

```
var sendData = function() {
  $.post(BASE_URL+'/part_request/request_insert', {
    data: { ids : ids_selected, request_to : 
       $('#request_to').val()} 
  }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
`sendData();
```

I want to put qty into array  [here pic of my array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihPpU.png)

Thank you

Comment: Please do not post image of code but the code itself

Comment: can you just post the sample input and expected output